# Perl `$$` variable

Tags: perl

What does the `$$` part mean in perl?

I found it in this code snippet:

```
my $unique   = "P$$" . "M$microseconds";
```

Comment: [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%24)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$$` means the current PID (Process ID). All predefined Perl variables can be found on the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) man page.

Answer (score 3):

It means the current process ID. See `man perlvar`.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, inherited the properties of Linux. It can accepted some features also. Like that , $$ which is the process ID of the current  process.